# Machine crashes with AHCI controller unavailable! and not using Asmedia Controller

Tags: linux, centos, software-raid, nvme, ahci

I have an Machine that crashes periodically. When I recreated the issue I found that the machine fails with the error AHCI controller unavailable! (full errors in the screenshot).
I have an AMD Ryzen 5 1600 CPU with a GA-A320M-H motherboard with 1 NVME drive (boot drive) and 6 regular HDD in 2 software raids.

Here is the screenshot of the error:
[Full errors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3bwD.jpg)

Also here is a paste with the full Machine details:
https://pastebin.com/XR1rZTJX

Comment: So, I found the problem.
It was an compound issue of an bad HDD with a ryzen c6 state bug.
As soon as I disconnected the bad HDD I started to get:
    BUG: soft lockup - CPU#12 stuck for 23s!
Since I wasn't able to mitigate the issue (despite the issue having workarounds) I just bought an Intel CPU (and compatible MOBO).
The PC now ran for two weeks with no problems.
If anyone is interested here's the bug report on the ryzen c6 state bug issue:
[https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196683](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196683)

Answer (score 0):

compound issue of an bad HDD with a ryzen c6 state bug.
As soon as I disconnected the bad HDD I started to get:

```
BUG: soft lockup - CPU#12 stuck for 23s!
```

here's the bug report on the ryzen c6 state bug issue:
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196683